# How to remove GRUB from Windows 8.1?

Tags: linux, windows-8, windows-8.1, fedora, grub

Awhile back ago I had installed Fedora 21 on my PC (with trouble of course). Anyways, fast forward today, I get tired of the dual boot (grub) screen and decide to wipe my linux partition thinking that would remove Fedora completely but I was wrong. After troubleshooting for a good bit I managed to boot up Windows 8 again, it was not recognizing it before.

So now at the moment I still get the GRUB screen with several options. Fedora Fedora etc. Windows Boot Manager Windows 8.1

I already tried the Windows 8 repair option but no luck. (cmd fixmbr commands) https://i.stack.imgur.com/RciCO.jpg (No Window Installs?)

My Partitions

My Boot/GRUB Screen

After I load up Windows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL0A3.jpg

(Windows loads fine after, but should I be seeing this?)

Also in BIOS my HD name is "Fedora" O_o

Answer (score 0):

`bootrec /fixmbr`

stage 1 of grub often resides in the mbr

another solution is when you see the grub screen press esc and type 
`lock windows10` (substitute whatever the windows option is called in the grub menu)

Comment: I tried the fixmbr command, see the screenshots.
http://imgur.com/a/S7ZBJ
Also, I tried the lock command in grub but it said the command did not exist.